# I want to write and read from a file and I have this error when I run : java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, serialization

I have this class Dictionar , implements Serializable and the class ScriereCitire 
package controler;

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class ScriereCitire {

    public void scriere(Dictionar dictionar){
        try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("dict.txt")){
            ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objOut.writeObject(dictionar);
            objOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {      
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Dictionar citire(){
        try(FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("dict.txt")){
            ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Dictionar dictionar = (Dictionar)objInput.readObject();
            objInput.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

I created a file named dict.txt in the project. I have a class maine where I call my GraphicInterface which calls ScriereCitire. But when I run it points to this as a error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at controler.ScriereCitire.citire(ScriereCitire.java:27)
    at view.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:46)
    at controler.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created an empty file somehow. Possibly you got an exception creating it and have ignored it.

> I created a file named dict.txt in the project

How? Why?

NB serialized data is not text and should not be placed in a file named .txt.

Comment: this question will be stupid. when i say that I created a file named dict, I mean right-click, file and I named it dict.txt. It is empty for sure. But is not suppose to be that way? My code should fill the file, right?

Comment: Of course. You got an `EOFException` trying to read an object from a file that didn't contain one. Why is this a surprise?